# Why are my ending marks red underlined?

Tags: android, listview

In my code the ending marks in my onItemClick(AdapterView are red, and I have no idea why... Have a look:

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);


    String listArray[] = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside",
            "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach", "Money" };
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= listArray.length - 1; i++) {
       HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("title", listArray[i]);
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    String[] sfrm = { "title"};
    int[] sto = { R.id.title};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
            R.layout.row_layout, sfrm, sto);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long id) {
           CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk);
           cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());

            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation8, R.anim.animation7);
    }
}
```

I'd be so grateful for a solution, this is bugging me like hell. Thanks in advance... :)

Edit: Here's a screenie: [image: a busy cat]

Comment: Who knows.  People that downvote without leaving comments really bug the hell out of me... But anyways, Simon's answer below should help you out - it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have closed one `}` that doesn't needed to be closed.

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
        Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);

        String listArray[] = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside", "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach",
                "Money" };
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= listArray.length - 1; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("title", listArray[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }
        String[] sfrm = { "title" };
        int[] sto = { R.id.title };
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.row_layout, sfrm, sto);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk);
                cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation8, R.anim.animation7);
    }
```

Comment: Yes or you can juste delete the first underlined `}`

Comment: Hmm.. Nothing is happening though. It doesn't crash but when I click on one of the rows the corresponding checkbox doesn't get ticked or unticked?